# Definition css style div element

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I work with javascript and I have the following  element. I want to apply a CSS style to change height: 100px of element iframe

```
<div tabindex="-1" 
class="mce-edit-area mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item"
 id="mceu_21" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;" hidefocus="1">
 <iframe title="Área de texto enriquecido. 
 Pulse ALT-F9 para el menu. Pulse ALT-F10 para la barra de herramientas.
 Pulse ALT-0 para ayuda" id="text1_ifr" src='javascript:""' 
 frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; display: block;" allowtransparency="true">
</iframe></div>
```

How do I have to define the CSS style?

Comment: Do you want to change the height of the iFrame and just searching for the command to do this with javascript?

Comment: Did you try using the attribute height = "100" ?

Comment: I want to apply a CSS style

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the iframe first

```
<iframe class="height-100"></iframe>
```

In CSS provide your styling,

```
iframe .height-100 {
  height: 100px;
}
```

use `height: 100px !important` only as a last resort.

**Update:**

You have already provided styling to your iframe

```
style="width: 100%; height: 100px;"
```

that should have worked, use `element select` and check if its getting overridden by something else.

Answer (score -2):

define style element in head tag

```
<style>
iframe {
    width: 100px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: How can I define style for element  id="mceu_21"?

Comment: @user3712581 you will have to use # in front of the id , check [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)